# What is the best way to split a string by a delimiter functionally?

Tags: string, haskell, split

I tried to write the program in Haskell that will take a string of integer numbers delimitated by comma, convert it to list of integer numbers and increment each number by 1.

For example
`"1,2,-5,-23,15" ->  [2,3,-4,-22,16]`

Below is the resulting program

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- return 1
  putStrLn . show . map (+1) . map toInt . splitByDelimiter delimiter
    $ getList n

getList :: Int -> String
getList n = foldr (++) [] . intersperse [delimiter] $ replicate n inputStr

delimiter = ','

inputStr = "1,2,-5,-23,15"

splitByDelimiter :: Char -> String -> [String]
splitByDelimiter _ "" = []
splitByDelimiter delimiter list =
  map (takeWhile (/= delimiter) . tail)
    (filter (isPrefixOf [delimiter])
       (tails
           (delimiter : list)))

toInt :: String -> Int
toInt = read
```

The most hard part for me was programming of function `splitByDelimiter` that take a String and return list of Strings

`"1,2,-5,-23,15" ->  ["1","2","-5","-23","15"]`

Thought it is working, I am not happy with the way it is written. There are a lot of parentheses, so it looks Lisp like. Also the algorithm is somewhat artificial:

1. Prepend delimiter to beginning of string `",1,2,-5,-23,15"`
2. Generate list of all tails `[",1,2,-5,-23,15", "1,2,-5,-23,15", ",2,-5,-23,15", .... ]`
3. Filter and left only strings that begins with delimiter `[",1,2,-5,-23,15", ",2,-5,-23,15", .... ]`
4. Drop first delimiter and take symbols until next delimiter will be met `["1", "2", .... ]`

**So the questions are:**

How I can improve function `splitByDelimiter`?

Can I remove prepend and drop of delimiter and make direct split of string?

How I can rewrite the function so there will be less parentheses?

May be I miss something and there are already standard function with this functionality?

Comment: `foldr (++) []` is otherwise known as `concat`, `putStrLn . show` is otherwise known as `print`.  Also, `n <- return 1` is a little odd; you can just do `let n = 1` and avoid wrapping and unwrapping the monad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978578/how-to-split-a-string-in-haskell)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Doesn't [Data.List.Split.splitOn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.2.3/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitOn) do this?

Comment: Whereas this package is not part of the basic install (Haskell Platform), I think it tends to get overlooked.

Comment: `splitOneOf` is a generally more useful function, especially if you need to take arbitrary whitespace into account.

Answer (score 26):

```
splitBy delimiter = foldr f [[]] 
            where f c l@(x:xs) | c == delimiter = []:l
                             | otherwise = (c:x):xs
```

Edit: not by the original author, but below is a more (overly?) verbose, and less flexible version (specific to `Char`/`String`) to help clarify how this works.  Use the above version because it works on any list of a type with an `Eq` instance.

```
splitBy :: Char -> String -> [String]
splitBy _ "" = [];
splitBy delimiterChar inputString = foldr f [""] inputString
  where f :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
        f currentChar allStrings@(partialString:handledStrings)
          | currentChar == delimiterChar = "":allStrings -- start a new partial string at the head of the list of all strings
          | otherwise = (currentChar:partialString):handledStrings -- add the current char to the partial string

-- input:       "a,b,c"
-- fold steps:
-- first step:  'c' -> [""] -> ["c"]
-- second step: ',' -> ["c"] -> ["","c"]
-- third step:  'b' -> ["","c"] -> ["b","c"]
-- fourth step: ',' -> ["b","c"] -> ["","b","c"]
-- fifth step:  'a' -> ["","b","c"] -> ["a","b","c"]
```

Comment: This is brilliant; it took me way too long to understand how it works, but I love it.

Comment: Doesn't work for empty strings, though, i.e. it evaluates to `[""]` rather than `[]`.

Comment: I agree with @ljedrz - it took me way to long to understand, but it is brilliant!  I hope you don't mind but I added a less flexible, but extremely verbose addendum to your answer to help other people understand what's happening.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but this is the functionality I would expect for a `splitOn` function, not `splitBy`. For `splitBy` I would expect `splitBy fn = foldr f [[]] where f c l@(x:xs) = bool ((c:x):xs) ([]:l) $ fn c`, with the current `splitOn c` functionality recovered by `splitOn c = splitBy (==c)`

Answer (score 12):

This is a bit of a hack, but heck, it works.

```
yourFunc str = map (+1) $ read ("[" ++ str ++ "]")
```

Here is a non-hack version using `unfoldr`:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow(second)

-- break' is like break but removes the
-- delimiter from the rest string
break' d = second (drop 1) . break d

split :: String -> Maybe (String,String)
split [] = Nothing
split xs = Just . break' (==',') $ xs

yourFunc :: String -> [Int]
yourFunc = map ((+1) . read) . unfoldr split
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good point of view. I like the way how unfoldr is used here.

Comment: Your split is faster than splitOn by 43ns on my comp in ghci :)

Comment: This implementation of split function works differently than you would expect - it doesn't properly split strings with commas at the end - one "" is missing. If you want to make sure that a split function is 100% functional, it should be reversible by interspersing with the same delimiter for all permutations of a delimited string, eg. "a,b,c".

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here is how you could create a simple parser with Parsec:

```
module Main where

import Control.Applicative hiding (many)
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

line :: Parser [Int]
line = number `sepBy` (char ',' *> spaces)

number = read <$> many digit
```

One advantage is that it's easily create a parser which is flexible in what it will accept:

```
*Main Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.Token> :load "/home/mikste/programming/Temp.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/mikste/programming/Temp.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.Token> parse line "" "1, 2, 3"
Right [1,2,3]
*Main Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.Token> parse line "" "10,2703,   5, 3"
Right [10,2703,5,3]
*Main Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.Token>
```

Comment: Minor, but could use `many1` as in `number = read <$> many1 digit` so that invalid input like "1,,2" results in a Left value instead of an exception from Prelude.read.

Answer (score 4):

This is application of HaskellElephant's answer to original question with minor changes

```
splitByDelimiter :: Char -> String -> [String]
splitByDelimiter = unfoldr . splitSingle

splitSingle :: Char -> String -> Maybe (String,String)
splitSingle _ [] = Nothing
splitSingle delimiter xs =
  let (ys, zs) = break (== delimiter) xs in
  Just (ys, drop 1 zs)
```

Where the function splitSingle split the list in two substrings by first delimiter.

For example:
`"1,2,-5,-23,15" -> Just ("1", "2,-5,-23,15")`

Answer (score 2):

```
splitBy del str = helper del str []   
    where 
        helper _ [] acc = let acc0 = reverse acc in [acc0] 
        helper del (x:xs) acc   
            | x==del    = let acc0 = reverse acc in acc0 : helper del xs []  
            | otherwise = let acc0 = x : acc     in helper del xs acc0
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine 
use:- split "Your string" [] and replace ',' with any delimiter

```
split [] t = [t]
split (a:l) t = if a==',' then (t:split l []) else split l (t++[a])
```

Comment: repeated singletons appending on the right is an anti-pattern (leads to quadratic behavior).

Answer (score 1):

```
import qualified Text.Regex as RegExp

myRegexSplit :: String -> String -> [String]
myRegexSplit regExp theString = 
  let result = RegExp.splitRegex (RegExp.mkRegex regExp) theString
  in filter (not . null) result

-- using regex has the advantage of making it easy to use a regular
-- expression instead of only normal strings as delimiters.

-- the splitRegex function tends to return an array with an empty string
-- as the last element. So the filter takes it out

-- how to use in ghci to split a sentence
let timeParts = myRegexSplit " " "I love ponies a lot"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another without imports:

```
splitBy :: Char -> String -> [String]
splitBy _ [] = []
splitBy c s  =
  let
    i = (length . takeWhile (/= c)) s
    (as, bs) = splitAt i s
  in as : splitBy c (if bs == [] then [] else tail bs)
```

Comment: use of `length` is an anti-pattern (destroys laziness), use `span`/`break` instead; `(if bs == [] then [] else tail bs)` == `drop 1 bs`.