# Importing Prelude function, doctest says 'Not in scope'

Tags: haskell

Trying to use Prelude's built in function to listify a string by space delimiter, as described by SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981265/1234721).

I have the following:

```
module MiniForth
  ( functions
  , ...
  ) where
import Data.Char  -- I actually import here
import Prelude hiding (words) -- this avoids the ambiguity in the words function when declaring it locally

words :: String -> [String]
-- ^ Takes a string and breaks it into separate words delimited by a space
--
--   Examples:
--
--   >> words "break this string at spaces"
--   ["break","this","string","at","spaces"]
--
--   >> words ""
--   []
--
words s =  case dropWhile Char.isSpace s of
                      "" -> []
                      s' -> w : words s''
                            where (w, s'') = break Char.isSpace s'
```

but I still get the error when running Doctest:

```
Not in scope: ‘Char.isSpace’
```

for both lines.  I have imported it, so why is it not in scope?

Comment: Try removing `Char.` in front of `isSpace`. Or `import qualified Data.Char as Char`.

Comment: Throw it up as an answer, and ill award :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
import Data.Char
```

puts `isSpace` into scope, without the `Char.` prefix. Hence, it is sufficient to remove said prefix.

Otherwise,

```
import qualified Data.Char as Foo
```

will put `Foo.isSpace` into scope (as well as the rest of the imported module), using any prefix `Foo.` of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got good suggestions, but as a further explanation, what probably happened here is that the code you were trying to adapt used the *old* Haskell98 name of the `Data.Char` module, which was simply `Char`. (You can still import it that way if you enable GHC's Haskell98 mode.)

The hierarchical module names with dots in them were added a while after the H98 standard, as an afterthought when people saw that a completely flat module namespace was impractical. But this was done in a minimal way, simply adding `.` as an allowed character in module names.

In particular, module names are not *divisible* in Haskell: Importing the module name `Data.Char` does not in itself give you any access to using `Char` as a module prefix.

So if you *did* want to include a module prefix before `isSpace`after doing just `import Data.Char`, it would have to be with the full module name: `Data.Char.isSpace`.