# Correct usage of `reads` to return tuple of Int and String

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use the `reads` function from Prelude, and doctest to test it.  Just loading GHCI and typing `reads "57x"` or `Prelude.reads "57x"` yields only an empty list `[]`, so I thought I had to import the function myself.   According to the docs, it should return a tuple.  But running Doctest and in GHCI, I get the error `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` when putting in any test that has characters in addition to the Integer, ie `54x`.   What do I need to change to get it to return the proper tuple, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2488528/1234721), but with INTs instead of DOUBLEs?

I have a haskell file that looks like this:

```
module StackOverflow where
import Prelude hiding (words, reads)

reads :: String -> [(Int, String)]
-- ^ Takes a string, like "57" and reads the corresponding integer value
--   out of it. It returns an empty list if there is a failure, or a list
--   containing one tuple, with the integer value as the first element of
--   the tuple and a (possibly empty) string of remaining unconvertable extra
--   characters as the second element.
--
--   Examples:
--
--   >>> reads "57"
--   [(57,"")]
--
--   >>> reads "57x"
--   [(57,"x")]
--
reads s = [(read s :: Int,"")]
```

Comment: Do you want to use the builtin `reads` or define your own?

Comment: I was trying to use my own and override Preludes given the predefined one wasn't working in the GHCI interpreter.

Comment: What was it doing when you tried to use the Prelude one? Are you only trying to write a new one because the Prelude one didn't seem to work?

Comment: Correct.  If I just have the following in a file `module Test where import Prelude` with or without the `import Prelude`, typing `reads "54x"` or `Prelude.reads "54x"` with or without the `x`, I still just get an empty list `[]`.   This is why I added the function myself, and had problems with `words` as noted in my SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075481/importing-prelude-function-doctest-says-not-in-scope)

Comment: That is due to something called type defaulting. Because of `reads` polymorphic signature, you need to provide a type signature so it knows what type you are expecting. Try `reads "54x" :: [(Int, String)]`. I believe it defaults to the type `[((), String)]` if there is no type signature, and `[]` would be the correct result in that case.

Comment: any places to read about this, cause I did not know that you could declare the type in the function call

Comment: You can add a type signature to any expression. The keywords for this issue are "type defaulting" and "monomorphism restriction" (the second one can be sort of technical and isn't necessary to fully understand in order to understand what's going on with `reads` though). It is basically because the type must be known at compile time, but there is no way for it to predict what it will be (since functions are called at runtime). It makes a guess in the absence of a type signature in order to statically determine the types, but in this case the guess doesn't work.

Comment: post an answer and I'll credit.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DavidYoung the monomorphism restriction has been turned off by default in GHCi for a while, and I believe it'll also be turned off by default in GHC 7.10.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting a "no parse" exception is that the type is defaulting to something other than `Int` (in this case, `()`). So, effectively, the expression `reads "54x"` is being evaluated at the type `[((), String)]`. This is because in order to select the appropriate `Read` instance, the type must be fully specified at compile time but this isn't possible because it doesn't know what the `String` is expected to contain.

You can tell it what type you are expecting from the `String` by providing an explicit type signature, like this

```
reads "54x" :: [(Int, String)]
```

All expressions can be given an explicit type signature and, in fact, sometimes it is necessary in order to avoid an ambiguous type.