# Split string on multiple delimiters of any length in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, split, functional-programming

I am attempting a Haskell coding challenge where, given a certain string with a prefix indicating which substrings are delimiting markers, a list needs to be built from the input.

I have already solved the problem for multiple single-length delimiters, but I am stuck with the problem where the delimiters can be any length.  I use splitOneOf from Data.List.Split, but this works for character (length 1) delimiters only.

For example, given

**input** `";,\n1;2,3,4;10"`,

**delimiters** are `';'` and `','`

**splitting** the input on the above delivers

**output** `[1,2,3,4,10]`

The problem I'm facing has two parts:

Firstly, a single delimiter of any length, e.g.

`"****\n1****2****3****4****10"` should result in the list `[1,2,3,4,10]`.

Secondly, more than one delimiter can be specified, e.g.

**input** `"[***][||]\n1***2||3||4***10"`,

**delimiters** are `"***"` and `"||"`

**splitting** the input on the above delivers

**output** `[1,2,3,4,10]`

My code for retrieving the delimiter in the case of character delimiters:

```
--This gives the delimiters as a list of characters, i.e. a String.
getDelimiter::String->[Char]
getDelimiter text = head . splitOn "\n" $ text

--drop "[delimiters]\n" from the input
body::String->String
body text = drop ((length . getDelimiter $ text)+1)) $ text 

--returns tuple with fst being the delimiters, snd the body of the input
doc::String->(String,String) 
doc text = (getDelimiter text, body text)

--given the delimiters and the body of the input, return a list of strings
numbers::(String,String)->[String]
numbers (delim, rest) = splitOneOf delim rest

--input ",@#\n1,2@3#4" gives output ["1","2","3","4"]
getList::String->[String]
getList text = numbers . doc $ text
```

So my question is, how do I do the processing for when the delimiters are e.g. `"***"` and `"||"`?

Any hints are welcome, especially in a functional programming context.

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: Show us some code and its sample input and expected output.

Comment: That's really not clear to me. Could you show us two or three examples, well formatted, with the expected inputs and outputs ?

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. Did you try to use successively Data.List.Split ? It is not convenient enough ?

Comment: Just a thought. `splitWhen (`elem` [';',',']) input` gives `["","","1","2","3","4","10"]`. Then you could remove the empty strings then.

Comment: Or something like that **filter (\x -> not $ elem x [";",",",";,"]) $ split (dropBlanks . condense $ whenElt (`elem` [';',','])) input**

Comment: sorry the markdown drops my backticks... that's tedious

Comment: I've already solved this problem for when the delimiting markers are characters, i.e. length of one.  The problem is when the delimiter is of unspecified length - this gets especially tricky, because the methods in Data.List.Split assume the delimiters are characters.  **splitOn** takes a string argument - what I need is essentially a **splitOn** that takes a list of strings

Comment: Is there some sort of contest going on? Or is this homework? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49211131/126014

Comment: You can use `splitWhen` followed by any condition, this way you're not restricted to lenght one characters.

Comment: @mark-seemann I'm attempting the coding exercise located at [codekata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) just for practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind making multiple passes over the input string, you can use `splitOn` from `Data.List.Split`, and gradually split the input string using one delimiter at a time.

You can write this fairly succinctly using `foldl'`:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

splitOnAnyOf :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOnAnyOf ds xs = foldl' (\ys d -> ys >>= splitOn d) [xs] ds
```

Here, the accumulator for the fold operation is a list of strings, or more generally `[[a]]`, so you have to 'lift' `xs` into a list, using `[xs]`.

Then you fold over the delimiters `ds` - not the input string to be parsed. For each delimiter `d`, you split the accumulated list of strings with `splitOn`, and concatenate them. You could also have used `concatMap`, but here I arbitrarily chose to use the more general `>>=` (*bind*) operator.

This seems to do what is required in the OP:

```
*Q49228467> splitOnAnyOf [";", ","] "1;2,3,4;10"
["1","2","3","4","10"]
*Q49228467> splitOnAnyOf ["***", "||"] "1***2||3||4***10"
["1","2","3","4","10"]
```

Since this makes multiple passes over temporary lists, it's most likely not the fastest implementation you can make, but if you don't have too many delimiters, or extremely long lists, this may be good enough.

Comment: Thank you! For my use case, this method is fine - my input strings will not be very long, so performance won't be an issue.

Comment: Prelude> [read n :: Int | n <- ["1","2","3","9","10"]] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[1,2,3,9,10]

Answer (score 2):

This problem has two kinds of solutions: the simple, and the efficient. I will not cover the efficient (because it is not simple), though I will hint on it.

But first, the part where you extract the `delimiter` and `body` parts of the input, may be simplified with `Data.List.break`:

```
delims = splitOn "/" . fst . break (== '\n')  -- Presuming the delimiters are delimited with
                                              -- a slash.
body   =               snd . break (== '\n')
```

In any way, we may reduce this problem to ***finding*** the positions of all the given ***patterns*** in a given ***string***. (By saying "string", I do not mean the haskell `String`. Rather, I mean an arbitrarily long sequence (or even an infinite *stream*) of any ***symbols*** for which an `Eq`uality relation is defined, which is typed in Haskell as `Eq a => [a]`. I hope this is not too confusing.) As soon as we have the positions, we may slice the string to our hearts' content. If we want to deal with an infinite stream, we must obtain the positions incrementally, and yield the results as we go, which is a restriction that must be kept in mind. Haskell is equipped well enough to handle the stream case as well as the finite string.

A **simple approach** is to cast `isPrefixOf` on the string, for each of the patterns.

- If some of them matches, we replace it with a `Nothing`.
- Otherwise we mark the first symbol as `Just` and move to the next position.

Thus, we will have replaced all the different delimiters by a single one: `Nothing`. We may then readily slice the string by it.

This is fairly idiomatic, and I will bring the code to your judgement shortly. The problem with this approach is that it is inefficient: in fact, if a pattern failed to match, we would rather advance by more than one symbol.

It would be **more efficient** to base our work on the research that has been made into finding patterns in a string; this problem is well known and there are great, intricate algorithms that solve it an order of magnitude faster. These algorithms are designed to work with a single pattern, so some work must be put into adapting them to our case; however, I believe they are adaptable. The simplest and eldest of such algorithms is the [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), and it is already [encoded](https://github.com/CindyLinz/Haskell-KMP) in Haskell. You may wish to take arms and generalize it − a quick path to some amount of fame.

Here is the code:

```
module SplitSubstr where

-- stackoverflow.com/questions/49228467

import Data.List (unfoldr, isPrefixOf, elemIndex)
import Data.List.Split (splitWhen)  -- Package `split`.
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes, isNothing)

-- | Split a (possibly infinite) string at the occurrences of any of the given delimiters.
--
-- λ take 10 $ splitOnSubstrs ["||", "***"] "la||la***fa"
-- ["la","la","fa"]
--
-- λ take 10 $ splitOnSubstrs ["||", "***"] (cycle "la||la***fa||")
-- ["la","la","fa","la","la","fa","la","la","fa","la"]
--
splitOnSubstrs :: [String] -> String -> [String]
splitOnSubstrs delims
    = fmap catMaybes       -- At this point, there will be only `Just` elements left.
    . splitWhen isNothing  -- Now we may split at nothings.
    . unfoldr f            -- Replace the occurences of delimiters with a `Nothing`.
  where

-- | This is the base case. It will terminate the `unfoldr` process.
    f [ ]  = Nothing

-- | This is the recursive case. It is divided into 2 cases:
-- * One of the delimiters may match. We will then replace it with a Nothing.
-- * Otherwise, we will `Just` return the current element.
--
-- Notice that, if there are several patterns that match at this point, we will use the first one.
-- You may sort the patterns by length to always match the longest or the shortest. If you desire
-- more complicated behaviour, you must plug a more involved logic here. In any way, the index
-- should point to one of the patterns that matched.
--
--                       vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    f body@(x:xs) = case elemIndex True $ (`isPrefixOf` body) <$> delims of
        Just index -> return (Nothing, drop (length $ delims !! index) body)
        Nothing    -> return (Just x, xs)
```

It might happen that you will not find this code straightforward. Specifically, the `unfoldr` part is somewhat dense, so I will add a few words about it.

`unfoldr f` is an embodiment of a recursion scheme. `f` is a function that may chip a part from the `body`: `f :: (body -> Maybe (chip, body))`.

- As long as it keeps chipping, `unfoldr` keeps applying it to the `body`. This is called *recursive case*.
- Once it fails (returning `Nothing`), `unfoldr` stops and hands you all the chips it thus collected. This is called *base case*.

In our case, `f` takes symbols from the string, and fails once the string is empty.

That's it. I hope you send me a postcard when you receive a Turing award for a fast splitting algorithm.